# Image disappears automatically in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I used the following code to display the image imageview when i click the table cell. It displays the image but disappeared within 1ms.
Can anyone help me to do that.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BeaconAdViewController *imageVC = [[BeaconAdViewController alloc] init];
    self.tempImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
    imageVC.tempImg.image = self.tempImg.image;
    imageVC.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss)];
    [imageVC.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
    [self presentViewController:imageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //self.fullImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
    self.tempImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
}

-(void)dismiss
{
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in Dismiss? try to put a breakpoint in dismiss method and see if it's called only upon tapping.
the code looks familiar lol

Comment: Marom can i have your contact details pls. I want to be friend with you. u r clearing lot of my doubts

Comment: my email is galmaroms@gmail.com. You welcome to send me a mail every-time you post here a message. Just send me a link and I will try to help

Comment: familiar code joke on me right..

Comment: dismiss is not calling even a single time

Comment: still its diappearing

Comment: if i comment [self presentViewController:imageVC animated:YES completion:nil]; its showing the image

Comment: what's self.tempImg? is it a placeholder?

Comment: As as far as I can understand your code - you click the cell and view controller with image is presented. And after 1ms the image disappears but view controller stay as it is right? And do you share the image? It looks like first you assign to `self.tempImg.image`. Is `self.tempImg` added to subviews somewhere?

Comment: @Gal Marom - tempIMg is the imageview that i have in my storyboard inside the UIView

Comment: So obviously it is presented in `self.tempImg` and in view controller as well, right? -- As more information you give us quicker we can help you. Right now your post doesn't say a lot.

Comment: @sumofighter666 - I click the cell in the table and it should display the image under the cell where i have a UIImage inside UIView

Comment: try removing the  self.tempImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]]; from viewDidAppear. I think there is a loop, which causes the image view to load again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BeaconAdViewController *imageVC = [[BeaconAdViewController alloc] init];
    // Change the below
    // self.tempImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
    imageVC.tempImg.image = theImage;
    imageVC.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss)];
    [imageVC.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
    [self presentViewController:imageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //self.fullImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
    self.tempImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
}

-(void)dismiss
{
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do

```
 imageVC.tempImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.tempImg.image];
```

you also needs to change

```
 -(void) dismiss{}
```

to:

```
 -(IBAction) dismiss : (id) sender {}
```

and the

```
 @selector(dismiss)
```

to
      @selector(dismiss:)

Comment: @sumofighter666 did you read the comments before you were voting down someone?